Latex landscape table doesn't fit page
I am trying to add a table to my article in landscape; however, it doesn't seem to fit on a single page. Instead the page, before the table, appears to block half of it.
x-post stackoverflow.com/q/78686021/2777074
This is how I have tried to do it,
MRE:
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  % Comment this line out
                                                          % if you need a4paper
%\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, conference]{ieeeconf}      % Use this line for a4
                                                          % paper

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              % This command is only
                                                          % needed if you want to
                                                          % use the \thanks command
\overrideIEEEmargins
% See the \addtolength command later in the file to balance the column lengths
% on the last page of the document

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}

\begin{document}

\newpage 
\appendix


\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{My caption}
  \label{my-label}
{\small %
    \begin{tabular}{p{.18\textwidth}p{.22\textwidth}p{.2\textwidth}p{.2\textwidth}p{.2\textwidth}}
Detection\par Methods & Supervised/\par Semi-supervised/\par Unsupervised & Technique Used & Applications & Technology \\
Statistical & & Gaussian-based detection & Online anomaly detection & Conventional data centres \\
Statistical & & Gaussian-based detection & General & General \\
Statistical & & Regression\par analysis & Globally-distributed commercial applications & Distributed, Web-based, Application \&\par System metrics \\
Statistical & & Regression\par analysis & Web applications & Enterprise web applications and conventional data centre \\
Statistical & & Correlation & Complex\par enterprise online applications & Distributed\par System \\
Statistical & & Correlation & Orleans system and distributed cloud computing services & Virtualized, cloud computing and distributed system (Orleans system) \\
Statistical & & Correlation & Hadoop,\par Olio and RUBiS & Virtualized cloud computing and distributed systems. \\
ĘMachine\par learning & Supervised & Bayesian\par classification & Online\par application & IBM system S-distributed stream\par processing\par cluster \\
Machine\par learning & Unsupervised & Neighbour-based technique (Local Outlier Factor algorithm) & General & Cloud\par Computing\par system \\
Machine\par learning & Semi-supervised & Principle component analysis and Semi-supervised Decision-tree\_ & Institute-wide cloud computing environment & Cloud\par Computing \\
Statistical & & Regression curve fitting the service time-adapted cumulative distributed function & Online\par application service & Platform and configuration agnostic \\
& & & & 
    \end{tabular}%
}%
\end{table}

\end{landscape}

This is how it looks in PDF: 
Would anyone know how to fix this issue?

\textwidth is the original, portrait, width, use \linewidth.

@DavidCarlisle thanks for your comment! I have tried this aswell; however, it does not solve the issue of the prior page blocking the table.

I can't guess what you mean by that, but landscape always starts a new page

unrelated but your commented out package list seems to have been written in 1995. graphics don't use, use graphicx, epsfig don't use. mathptm and times don't use, use newtx

If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/78686021/2777074

@DavidCarlisle sorry, I should reiterate. The table seems to not fit on the page, in fact, it also happens when it is not in landscape. You are correct about the packages, I used an overleaf template.

your column widths are too wide they need to add up to \linewidth but you need to account for 2\tabcolsep padding around each column.

Try the following table code:
\documentclass[conference]{ieeeconf}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % it load graphicx too

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}

\begin{document}
\appendix
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{My caption}
  \label{my-label}
\small %
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {X[0.5,l] 
                        X[0.5,l] 
                        X[1.2,l] 
                        X[l] 
                        X[l]},
             rowsep=3pt,
            }
    \toprule
Detection Methods 
    & Supervised/ Semi-supervised/ Unsupervised 
        & Technique Used    & Applications  & Technology                    \\
    \midrule
Statistical 
    &   & Gaussian-based detection
                            & Online anomaly detection 
                                            & Conventional data centres     \\
Statistical 
    &   & Gaussian-based detection 
                            & General       & General                       \\
Statistical 
     &  & Regression analysis 
                            & Globally-distributed commercial applications 
                                            & Distributed, Web-based, Application \& System metrics \\
Statistical 
    &   & Regression nalysis 
                            & Web applications 
                                            & Enterprise web applications and conventional data centre \\
Statistical 
    &   & Correlation & Complex\par enterprise online applications & Distributed\par System \\
Statistical 
    &   & Correlation & Orleans system and distributed cloud computing services & Virtualized, cloud computing and distributed system (Orleans system)        \\
Statistical 
    &   & Correlation & Hadoop,\par Olio and RUBiS 
                                            & Virtualized cloud computing and distributed systems.                \\
Machine\par learning 
Supervised 
    & Bayesian classification 
        & Online application 
                        & IBM system S-distributed stream processingcluster     \\
Machine\par learning 
    & Unsupervised 
        & Neighbour-based technique (Local Outlier Factor algorithm) 
                        & General           & Cloud\par Computing\par system    \\
Machine learning 
    & Semi-supervised 
        & Principle component analysis and Semi-supervised Decision-tree\_ 
                        & Institute-wide cloud computing environment 
                                            & Cloud\par Computing               \\
Statistical 
    &   & Regression curve fitting the service time-adapted cumulative distributed function 
                        & Online¸application service 
                                            & Platform and configuration agnostic \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}%
\end{table}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}

Above MWE fit table on one page:

